# fluent NHibernate: many-to-many relationship with Product to Product

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

fluent NHibernate:  many-to-many relationship with Product to Product.how i can implement it on asp.net mvc

```
public class Product
{    
       public virtual int Id { get; set; }
       public virtual IList<Product> ManyProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{    
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.ImageUrl);
    }
    HasManyToMany(x => x.ManyProduct)
         .Cascade.All()
         .Table("ProductInProduct");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specifically say what is wrong but your `HasManyToMany` definition needs to specify the Parent and Child Id columns from your `ProductInProduct` table:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.ManyProduct)
  .Table("ProductInProduct")
  .ParentKeyColumn("ParentId")
  .ChildKeyColumn("ChildId")
  .Cascade.All();
```