# Fluent NHibernate Many-to-Many Mapping Self Referencing with associative table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Just for record : I use C#, Fluent NHibernate, and MySQL 5.

I used to use NHibernate for this project, but recently I decided to use Fluent NHibernate instead. And I got problem in mapping the many to many relationship that references to self with additional column.

I have table **Item**. Item can has many component which is also from table **Item**. These components can be used by other item as well. 
For example, Item A needs two components, which are Item B and Item C. Item B is also used for Item D and Item E, and so on.

I used associative table and I need additional column for their relationship. Because of that, there will be 2 One - Many relations. This is my database structure.

1. Item

   - ID
   - Name
2. Prerequisite [ Associative table ]

   - ID
   - Item_ID [ FK_Item1 ] // item to be made.
   - Component_ID [ FK_Item2 ] // component for this item.
   - Weight // additional column.

This is my mapping for Prerequisite Table :

```
public PrerequisiteMap()
{
    Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Native();

    References(x => x.Item).Column("Item_ID");
    References(x => x.Component).Column("Component_ID");

    Map(x => x.Need);
}
```

This is my mapping for Item table :

```
public ItemMap()
{
    Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Native();

    HasMany(x => x.PrerequisitesParent).KeyColumn("Item_ID").Cascade.All();
    HasMany(x => x.PrerequisitesComponent).KeyColumn("Component_ID").Cascade.All ;

    Map(x => x.Name);
}
```

This is my prerequisite class :

```
public virtual UInt64 ID { get; set; }
// item.
public virtual UInt64 Item_ID { get; set; }
public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
// Component.
public virtual UInt64 Component_ID { get; set; }
public virtual Item Component { get; set; }

// prerequisite properties.
public virtual float Need { get; set; }
```

And this is my item class :

```
// Item properties.
public virtual UInt64 ID { get; protected set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual IList<Prerequisite> PrerequisitesComponent { get; set; }
public virtual IList<Prerequisite> PrerequisitesParent { get; set; }
```

The problem I have is, whenever I try to save/update Item with prerequisite, the Component_ID and Item_ID always have the same value. I create new Item X, with components Item Y and Item Z, in prerequisite table, I got these :

ID|Item_ID|Component_ID|Need

1 | X | X | 10

2 | X | X | 20

instead of, the expected result

1 | X | Y | 10

2 | X | Z | 20

This is my piece of code when saving :

```
    using (var session = SessionFactoryProvider.OpenSession())
    {
        using (var trans = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var item = session.Get<Item>((UInt64)1); // Item to be updated.
            var item2 = session.Get<Item>((UInt64)2); // Component 1
            var item3 = session.Get<Item>((UInt64)3); // Component 2

            item.PrerequisitesComponent.Add(new Prerequisite() { Item = item, Component = item2, Need = 100f}); // adding new prerequisite from component 1 (item2)
            item.PrerequisitesComponent.Add(new Prerequisite() { Item = item, Component = item3, Need = 100f }); // adding new prerequisite from component 2 (item3)

            session.SaveOrUpdate(item);
            try
            {
                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch(GenericADOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());
            }

        }

    }
```

What could be the problem here? Is it because I reference the same table? or maybe I mapped it wrongly?

I read other similar questions [many to many from product to product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916185/fluent-nhibernate-many-to-many-relationship-with-product-to-product) and  [many to many self referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811316/fluent-nhibernate-need-help-with-manytomany-self-referencing-mapping) but it seems like they didn't use additional column in their associative table?

Any help is very appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly Me.. I used the wrong reference for item.

I changed `item.PrerequisiteComponent` to `item.PrerequisiteParent` and it all works well.